# Geopy - ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler' from 'urllib.request'

Tags: python, https, urllib, importerror, geopy

When trying to import distance method from geopy.distance I am receiving the below error:

```
    from geopy.distance import distance
  File "C:\Users\cnethi\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\airbnb\lib\site-packages\geopy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from geopy.geocoders import *  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\cnethi\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\airbnb\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\__init__.py", line 120, in <module>
    from geopy.geocoders.arcgis import ArcGIS
  File "C:\Users\cnethi\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\airbnb\lib\site-packages\geopy\geocoders\arcgis.py", line 5, in <module>
    from geopy.compat import Request, string_compare, urlencode
  File "C:\Users\cnethi\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\envs\airbnb\lib\site-packages\geopy\compat.py", line 56, in <module>
    from urllib.request import (HTTPBasicAuthHandler, HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm,
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler' from 'urllib.request'
```

Can anyone please help in fixing this issue with 'HTTPSHandler' in 'urllib.request' file?

Python version - Earlier it was 3.5.x. I saw a post saying that updating python would fix it, but it didnot. Current version is 3.7.7. Also, I am using a virtual environment.

Github link for urllib.request - https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.8/Lib/urllib/request.py - There is a HTTPSHandler class, but it is inside an if statement.

Comment: Could you add your python version to the post? It would potentially help with replicating the problem and answering your question.

Comment: Have mentioned the python version in the post. Thanks.

Comment: What code are you running that gives you this error? Is it just the "from geopy.distance import distance" line? I ran that import and it works ok for me. python version 3.7.7, geopy version 1.21.0.

Comment: I am working on pandas data frame with latitude, longitude and some other columns, imported 'distance' from 'geopy' to calculate distance using latitude and longitude columns. But I am getting the error after including the line 'from geopy.distance import distance'.

Comment: you might want to try re-making your environment. It could be that one of your dependencies is clobbering urllib

Comment: It looks like your Python was built without `ssl` support. Most of the geocoders use https, so ssl support is mandatory for geopy. You can check if your Python is built with `ssl` like this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html#testing-for-ssl-support